# Can rails automatically find DB constraints and place this into your Model...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle-adf

As an Oracle ADF developer I am familiar with being able to create an Entity (the rails equivalent would be a Model) that includes all of the DB constraints (PK, FK, unique, length, any non-trigger induced constraint). As a result, in ADF I can very easily create a field on the view that is based on an Entities attribute.

For the sake of example, I place 3 such fields, one is a String (or VARCHAR2 in Oracle...) with a max length of 20, and the other is an INT and a DATE. The metadata (type, length constraints) are stored in the Model. And by default, any field generated with **automatically** include this validation on the front end. So, the first field, the `String(20)` will be a text input field with a max length of 20. So, **question 1**, will rails do this automatically on the front end or must I go and set this? Now, in ADF the int field that is placed on the view will not allow the user to enter non-digits (this will trigger on an attempt to update the Model (hitting submit, going to a new page). So, **question 2**, does rails automatically prevent non-digits? Also does rails have re-usable validation for simple things like phone numbers, addresses. Lastly, **question 3**, by default in ADF, any date will automatically generate a typical calendar widget for input. Does this also occur for rails? What does rails use for these kinds of javascript widgets if this isn't the case?

Answer (score 1):

Rails does recognise your datamodel automatically, but does not add any validation and stuff automatically. Not sure why not, because all the knowledge is there. I guess it has something to do with performance?

I know of one plugin that does this for you though: [dr. nic's magic-model-generator](http://github.com/drnic/magic_model_generator). It is not the same as ADF but it's a start. It investigates your datamodel and adds all the required validations and relations to your models.

As to dates, and forms, either you use something like [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), and then everything is somewhat automatic (adviseable). Or if you choose the more standard, manual way, use the [calendar-date-select](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/) gem (`gem install calendar_date_select`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, do you recommend any javascript frameworks to use with RoR? I am thinking to go that route instead of install a calendar widget/each other widget when needed. Maybe something like jquery ui.

Comment: jQuery and jQuery ui are a very good choice indeed. I use jQuery, and use a somewhat ad-hoc decision process :) While i personally prefer jQuery, i think you should also look at Netzke, http://netzke.org, which seems to be offering a cleaner integration between extjs and Rails.